# How to configure Jetty programmatically to execute JSP pages?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jetty, web.xml

I found some hints on Stackoverflow how to enable JSP support in Jetty by editing `web.xml`.

But can this be done programmatically, without any `web.xml`?
*(Preferable without writing an own servlet for that)*

*Even REST services support with Jersey [can be enabled programmatically](http://wikis.sun.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21725365) in Jetty. I can't believe that it's so hard for such wide-spread thing as JSP...*

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, I'm not sure...but if you're looking for simplicity, check out Maven. You can easily include the Jetty plugin in your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Then compile your code and start up the Jetty server with the command:

```
mvn clean compile jetty:run
```

Doesn't get much more simple than that. As long as you have your file structure adhere to Maven's standards, it'll take care of the rest.

Comment: I was talking about the runtime. The question was about `programmatically` doing something, so I was looking for an API-way to do certain things.   
Maven and others are build (and other kinds of) environments, but not runtime environments.